# Где размещается стек, если недостаточно памяти?

Tags: dos, стек, ассемблер

COM файл. Если 64К байтовый сегмент не имеет достаточно места для стека, то где DOS размещает этот стек и какой будет его адрес?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для com-файла (модель памяти tini) стек в любом случае будет начинаться от конца сегмента и расти к меньшим адресам. Если размер кода+данных вашей программы начнет приближаться к 64к, то нужно начинать думать о переходе на другую модель памяти (например, модель small, расширение программы будет exe), где для кода, данных, стека можно выделить собственные сегменты.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ